# What are the different frontends that can be set with OneupUploaderBundle?

Tags: symfony, vichuploaderbundle, oneupuploaderbundle

What are the different frontends that can be set with OneupUploaderBundle in the config.yml file?
I googled this and I found some frontend like: `mooupload`, `blueimp`.

What is the full list?

```
# app/config/config.yml
oneup_uploader:
    mappings:
        gallery:
            frontend: blueimp # or any uploader you use in the frontend
```

Is it possible to use [VichUploaderBunde](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) as frontend in [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VichUploaderBundle is not a "frontend" bundle. It just provides a way to handle uploads and persist them in entities/models.
You can use VichUploaderBundle or OneupUploaderBundle but not both. However, you should be able to use any frontend you want (dropzone, FineUploader, MooUpload, etc.), it will just require a bit of integration work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are curious about what type of configuration it supports and have no time to look in the [documentation](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md), then you can open the OneupUploaderBundle [Configuration.php](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php) and take a look inside:

```
 ->enumNode('frontend')
 ->values(array('fineuploader', 'blueimp', 'uploadify', 'yui3', 'fancyupload', 'mooupload', 'plupload', 'dropzone', 'custom'))
 ->isRequired()
```